# Java tabs ("\t") not working using FileWritter

Tags: java, string, file, tabs, filewriter

As you can see, after every text comes a tab, everything is working fine, but after third tab (see output) it generates a space not a tab.

```
fileWriter = new FileWriter(indexFile, true);
fileWriter.append(id).append("\t");
fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(idx)).append("\t");
fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(pageCount)).append("\t");
fileWriter.append(postal.toUpperCase()).append("\t"); <-- this one
fileWriter.append(address.toUpperCase());
fileWriter.append("\r\n");
```

My output:

```
00000347    1   1   FB-6666 DUMMY STREET 1 LAT
```

The problem comes after "FB-6666".

Any ideas on this?

Comment: This is how tabs work, they are not spaces

Comment: Look here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/O2DCc.png - they are all tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is writing a tab I promise - to convince yourself of this you should either open the resulting file in a hex editor and look at the value in that position, or add another character to the value before the tab and see how the format of the output changes.

Comment: Thank you!
I [checked](http://i.imgur.com/krc2jjU.png) and it generates a [0x09] HEX, which stands for a tab.

Comment: @Kefirchiks no problem, please accept one of the answers and upvote those that you found helpful

Answer (score 4):

No, it really *is* generating a tab - it's just that whatever you're using to view the file is deciding to handle tabs by aligning them to some boundary or other. If you make your `postal` value `FB-6666x` I suspect you'll then see a much larger space.

This *isn't* a problem with the file content at all.

If you want to enforce a certain number of spaces between columns, you'll need to write that many spaces. Alternatively, something else to view the file...

Answer (score 3):

Tabstops don't work this way. As the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop) states,

> Tab stops are set manually, and pressing the tab key causes the carriage to go to the next tab stop. In text editors on a computer, the same concept is implemented simplistically with automatic, fixed tab stops.

This means the tabstop will stop at a predefined position in the textfile, not after let's say the space it would take to insert a specific amount of spaces.